# How does one catch and handle errors in Make?

Tags: error-handling, makefile

I'm using GNU Make 3.80.

Within my Makefile_1, I am invoking Makefile_2.  In certain circumstances, Makefile_2 "throws" an error.

Is there a way for me to "catch" and "handle" (within Makefile_1) the error that Makefile_2 might possibly throw?

Comment: I'm currently researching a possible work-around using the ‘--ignore-errors’ flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have all the shell power you need:

```
target1:
    ${MAKE} -f Makefile_2 target2; \
    case "$$?" in \
    ... \
    esac;
```